# Es posible conectar Flutter con una base de datos remota?

Tags: base-de-datos, flutter

Es fácil encontrar tutoriales de cómo conectarse a una base de datos relacional (Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer) desde lenguajes tales como PHP, Java, Python, entre otros.  Es posible hacerlo desde Flutter, sin requerir otros lenguajes ni frameworks adicionales en el servidor (remoto) que aloja la base de datos?

Comment: Si es posible pero no recomendado para las aplicaciones moviles es preferible un API para mayor seguridad, ya que asi estas propenso a una inyeccion

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario @ChristianGtz

Answer (score 2):

Sí, es posible.
Por ejemplo, para MySQL podes usar el paquete [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1):

Conectarse a la db:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 3306,
  user: 'bob',
  password: 'wibble',
  db: 'mydb'
);
var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
```

Hacer una consulta con parámetros:

```
var userId = 1;
var results = await conn.query('select name, email from users where id = ?', [userId]);
```

*Si googleas "dart mysql" vas a encontrar varios tutoriales.*

---

También podrías crear una API Rest, o usar [Firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/).

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario @favcau.  Aún está muy en pañales éste tipo de librerías; la que indicas está en 0.17, pero ya veremos el avance :)